# Display NSMutableArray objects as text in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey I am trying to display objects from `NSMutableArray` as text in `UITextView` and I am getting a problem:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'NSString *')
```

Any suggestions how can it be done?

Here is the Code:

```
for (id obj in Mview.arrayTape)
viewTape.text = Mview.arrayTape.removeLastObject + @"/n" + viewTape.text;
```

*viewTape is an UITextView , arrayTape is the NSMutableArray passed from another view*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeLastObject` returns **[nothing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeLastObject)** (void) and you are appending it result to make a new string:

> viewTape.text = **Mview.arrayTape.removeLastObject +** @"/n" +
>   viewTape.text;

Try this instead: (`untested`)

```
for (NSString* obj in Mview.arrayTape)
{
    viewTape.text = [viewTape.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", obj];
}
```

Assuming `obj` is a type of `NSString`, if it is not use its corresponding string representation.

**EDIT**

Another approach. not yet offered by other solutions, **no need** to use `for loop`

```
 viewTape.text = [Mview.arrayTape componentsJoinedBy:@"\n"]
```

Comment: you are missing a * after NSString

Answer (score 1):

`Mview.arrayTape.removeLastObject` has the return type `void` i.e. it does not have a return value. And you cannot concatenate nothing with a string because `void` does not have a type (or class).

I guess what you want is this:

```
viewTape.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",(NSString *)Mview.arrayTape.lastObject,viewTape.text];
```

You can remove the last object *afterwards* if intended:

```
[Mview.arrayTape removeLastObject];
```

Comment: Objective-C does NOT have string concatenation with '+'. This will only create more errors.

Comment: You are right. I did not realize that second problem with the code. I updated my reply.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this method `removeLastObject` do not returns anything, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeLastObject). You should get the last object and get the string value add it (append it) to text in text view and the remove if required